# Доработка меню (Резиновое меню)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, menu

Есть [проект](http://www.samodelkin66.ru). Переделываю меню, контейнеров нет, ширину задаю в `%` (под популярные разрешения дисплеев через медиазапросы).

Но вот вопрос, при изменении разрешения дисплея, меню вылазит сразу же, то есть не уменьшается в процентном соотношении.
Подскажите как это исправить?

Часть кода меню:

```css
 .dropdown-submenu {
 position: relative;
 }
 .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    /*white-space: normal;*/
}
 .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 margin-top: -6px;
 margin-left: -1px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
 border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
 }
 
 .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
 display: block;
 }
 
 .dropdown-submenu>a:after {
 display: block;
 content: " ";
 float: right;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-color: transparent;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
 border-left-color: #cccccc;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-right: -10px;
 }
 
 .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
 border-left-color: #ffffff;
 }
 
 .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
 float: none;
 }
 
 .dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
 left: -100%;
 margin-left: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
 border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
 }
 @media (max-width: 1980px) {
 ul.dropdown-menu.number_one {
  width: 153%;
}
 ul.dropdown-menu.number_one_2 {
  width: 107%;
}
}
 @media (max-width: 1680px) {
 ul.dropdown-menu.number_one {
  width: 139%;
}
 ul.dropdown-menu.number_one_2 {
  width: 90%;
}
}
 @media (max-width: 1600px) {
 ul.dropdown-menu.number_one {
  width: 130%;
}
 ul.dropdown-menu.number_one_2 {
  width: 90%;
}
}
 @media (max-width: 1440px) {
 ul.dropdown-menu.number_one {
  width: 111.5%;
}
 ul.dropdown-menu.number_one_2 {
  width: 90%;
}
}
 @media (max-width: 1366px) {
 ul.dropdown-menu.number_one {
  width: 103%;
}
 ul.dropdown-menu.number_one_2 {
  width: 90%;
}
}
 @media (max-width: 1280px) {
 ul.dropdown-menu.number_one {
  width: 194.5%;
}
 ul.dropdown-menu.number_one_2 {
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
 white-space: normal;
}
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootstraptema.ru/plugins/2015/bootstrap3/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;">
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Механизированные инструменты</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu number_one">
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Электроинструменты</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu number_one_2">
 <li><a href="#">Аккумуляторные отвертки</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Сетевые шуруповерты</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">УШМ (болгарки)</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Отбойные молотки</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Лобзики</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Пилы торцовочные</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Пилы цепные</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Электрорубанки</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Степлеры и ножницы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Граверы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Гайковерты (электро)</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Аккумуляторные инструменты</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Дрели</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Перфораторы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Миксеры (электро)</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Пилы циркулярные</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Пилы сабельные</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Фены</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Шлифовальные машины</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Краскопульты электрические</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Штроборезы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Принадлежности к электроинструменту</a></li>
 
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Станки</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Станки распиловочные</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Лобзиковые станки</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Токарные станки</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Станки рейсмусовые</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Электроплиткорезы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Ленточные пилы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Станки сверлильные</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Станки шлифовальные</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Станки фуговально-рейсмусовые</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Точила</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Силовое оборудование</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Генераторы (электростанции)</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Принадлежности для генераторов</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Сварочное оборудование</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Строительное оборудование</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Виброплиты</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Мотопомпы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Швонарезчики</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Бетономешалки</a></li>

 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Насосное оборудование</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Насосные станции</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Насосы фонтанные</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Насосы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Принадлежности для насосов</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Тепло и клининговое оборудование</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Тепловое оборудование</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Пылесосы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Мойка</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Пневматика</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Компрессоры</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Принадлежности для пневмоинструмента</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Пистолеты пневматические</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Инженерная сантехника и инстументы</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Сантехника</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Трубы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Запорная арматура</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Уплотнительные материалы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Прочистное оборудование</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Фитинги</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Подводка</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Сантех оборудование</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Каталог сантехтоваров</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Сантехнические инструменты</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Для подготовки труб</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Резьбонарезной инструмент</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Сад и огород</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Садовая техника</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Бензопилы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Газонокосилки бензиновые</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Газонокосилки электро</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Кусторезы (электро)</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Принадлежности к бензоинструменту</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Бензокосы и триммеры</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Триммеры электро</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Измельчители</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Аэраторы, скарификаторы, воздуховки</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Культиваторы и мотоблоки</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Инструменты для почвы</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Тачки</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Культиваторы, мотыги, плуги</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Принадлежности для работы с почвой</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Лопаты, вилы, грабли</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Ручные инструменты для почвы</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Инструменты для полива</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Шланги, катушки для шлангов</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Распылители ручные</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Распылители стационарные</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Инструменты для растений</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Секаторы</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
 <a href="#">Товары для отдыха и пикника</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Термосы</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Горелки туристические</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: что значит меню вылазит?
если параметр width  больше 100% это значит что ширина будет больше окна просмотра, если хотите чтобы ширина была равна ширине окна просмотра width всегда должен быть 100%

Comment: а вообще уточните вопрос

Comment: сайт сделан таблицами <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="70%" align="center"> (то есть исходя с отрезка кода выше, эта таблица и контент в ней будет равен 70% от разрешения экрана) в этой таблице статичное меню находится здесь <td valign="top" style="width:10%;background:#FFFFFF;padding:5px;"> 
При наведении на него уже появляются 2 уровни и третье, задача в том, что бы эти вторые и третье уровни были всегда вровень с правым краем (то есть не вылазили за него) естественно задали ширину для них больше 100% так как при ширине в 100% они просто не доходят до края.

Comment: Не понимаю как сделать в этом случае более правильно

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nb867v Это что за?

Comment: так у тебя в коде нет Тейбл тэгов.

Comment: Меню полное Г. Сорри за прямоту.

Comment: Спасибо всем,  уже завершил работу.